# Rails: Hack/workaround: Is there a way to return/(stop execution) in the middle of a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

EDIT: Please don't worry about best practice. I am looking for a hack on this. Again, I don't want to use this in a team. Thanks for understanding.

I have a view file called index.html.haml

```
- if this.that?
  %div#if
    ....
    ....
- else
  %div#else
    ....
    ....
```

But I want to do this:

```
- if this.that?
  %div#if
    ....
    ....
    - return
%div#else
  .....
  .....
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Don't. Use two views, and choose to render one or the other. Your views shouldn't contain that kind of high-level conditional logic.

Comment: Well, I know that views shouldn't contain such logic - but this is an MVP and trying to not waste my time in using two partials :/

Comment: When the if condition is true, anyway the code in the else block will not be executed. If I am not wrong in getting what you mean to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit into the `haml` source code I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
- return @haml_buffer.buffer
```

In case you need the same hack for `.erb` you should add

```
<% return @output_buffer %>
```

Putting one of the above in one of your view files it will "flush" out all the contents that have been concatenated to the buffer up to that point.

Answer (score 4):

I know that it is not polite to answer a question with another one, but: Did you even try?

Sure you can! The code in ERB templates is evaluated as plain ruby and so you can use `return` in there as well. It is often required to return "something", like `return ''`.

It is not considered a "best practice" though, like @meagar already stated in the comments. Especially if you do it deep inside a template or partial. That is really bad style, your coworkers will hate you for that. A punch in the face is common in such situations.

Once a while i use `return` in partials when there is nothing to render like `return if Rails.env.production?` but that is rare and also pretty obvious when it's the first line in a partial.

Comment: I tried this in haml. return doesn't go well with haml. return "" doesn't show the view at all (not even the code above it - I guess it internally it thinks the blank string is the view content) Please don't assume I haven't tried it.

Comment: Also, please note that the code snippet is in haml and not ERB. I believe that you didn't see the intricate details. :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need a "hack" per se. You may just need the **[cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells)** gem as this gives you a little cell with MVC in portion of the view you're rendering.

Most likely this will handle the Model-View-Presenter the way you are trying to. :)

Answer (score 0):

I like the cells gem idea, but perhaps if you must, just include a

```
flash[:something] = this.that?
```

in the controller and use something to absorb that in a data-field somewhere in the dom for you to perform your logic via javascript.

```
:javascript
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var a  = $("h1").data("that")
```

do something if a == ? like hide the else %div

```
 })
```